# Why video played by VLC media player are blurred compared to MPV media player?

Tags: 14.04, video, vlc, ffmpeg, media

Image 1 is VLC media player image and Image 2 is MPV media player image respectively. Details as follows:

> Video Details:

- Format: `x264 1080p .mkv`
- File size: `10.5 GB`

> VLC media player version:

- VideoLAN - VLC 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (WeatherWax)

> MPV media player version:

- mpv git-061b947 (C) 2000-2015 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects
  built on Mon Aug 31 21:24:46 UTC 2015
- ffmpeg library versions:

  - libavutil       54.31.100
  - libavcodec      56.59.100
  - libavformat     56.40.101
  - libswscale      3.1.101
  - libavfilter     5.39.100
  - libswresample   1.2.101
- ffmpeg version: N-74700-g628a73f

> Operating system:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

> VLC media player screenshot:

[image: VLC media player screenshot]

> MPV media player screenshot:

[image: MPV media player screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and it helped:

Go to Tools -> Preferences -> Show settings: All -> Video -> Output modules -> OpenGL

There set `OpenGL extension` to `GLX and Open GL/GLES hardware` to `VA-API ... for X11` (as in my case I'm still using X11). Restart the player to see the effect!